# output of 'ulimit -c' and posix: whats showing?

Tags: bash, posix, ulimit

I have inherited some scripts where 'ulimit -c ' is set and 'set -o posix' and giving me as a result twice the value or half if I  turn it off again.
I see this on "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)" and on "release 7.9 (Maipo)".

How to replicate:

```
[app@host] ~ $ ulimit -c
2048
[app@host] ~ $ set  -o posix
[app@host] ~ $ ulimit -c
4096
```

Is it only a display issue?
Why is this happening, can someone please explain.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the `bash` manual entry (on my Ubuntu machine):

> "Values are in 1024-byte increments, except for -t, which is in seconds; -p, which is in units  of  512-byte blocks;  -P,  -T, -b, -k, -n, and -u, which are unscaled values; and, **when in posix mode, -c and -f, which are in 512-byte increments**."

---

So ...

> Is it only a display issue?

No.  It would affect the setting of limits too.

> Why is this happening, can someone please explain.

Because the documentation says so.  (Presumably, the `bash` developers thought that 1024 was a more natural / expected unit for `-c` and `-f`.)